# HTTP GET returning binary in instead of text

Tags: c#, http, httpclient

I want to get a *csv* file from a *http* application, MicroStrategy, but in instead I get a binary that can be opened in Excel but not in a text editor.

When I use the same *url* in a browser it downloads as text and so can be opened in a text editor.

This are the relevant (I think) lines:

```cs
HttpClient cliente;
cliente = new HttpClient(handler) { BaseAddress = uri, Timeout = new TimeSpan(0, 30, 0) };
...
string csv;
responseMessage = await cliente.GetAsync(uri);
HttpContentHeaders contentHeaders = responseMessage.Content.Headers;
csv = await responseMessage.Content.ReadAsStringAsync();
File.WriteAllText(caminhoArquivo, csv, Encoding.UTF8);
```

The headers show the correct *Content-Type*:

```
responseMessage.Content.Headers = {Content-Length: 6188
Content-Disposition: attachment;filename=Grupo Cont%C3%A1bil.txt;
Content-Type: text/plain
}
```

Just reading bytes and writing bytes this is the file in a hex viewer:

```
byte[] bytes;
bytes = await responseMessage.Content.ReadAsByteArrayAsync();
File.WriteAllBytes(caminhoArquivo, bytes);

  Offset: 00 01 02 03 04 05 06 07 08 09 0A 0B 0C 0D 0E 0F   
00000000: 47 00 72 00 75 00 70 00 6F 00 20 00 43 00 6F 00    G.r.u.p.o...C.o.
00000010: 6E 00 74 00 EF BF BD 00 62 00 69 00 6C 00 0D 00    n.t.o?=.b.i.l...
00000020: 0A 00 0D 00 0A 00 47 00 72 00 75 00 70 00 6F 00    ......G.r.u.p.o.
```

Comment: Can you show the code you use to write the csv data to a file?

Comment: You may want to try adding `cliente.DefaultRequestHeaders.Add("Accept", "text/csv")` before .GetStringAsync

Comment: @ekke: Now shown

Comment: @MarkArend: Tried both _text/csv_ and _text/plain_.

Comment: What happens when you open it in a text editor?

Comment: How about File.WriteAllText(caminhoArquivo, Encoding.UTF8.GetString(csv), Encoding.UTF8)

Comment: @LasseV.Karlsen: It shows binary garbage

Comment: @fluidguid: The same result: `csv = Encoding.UTF8.GetString(await responseMessage.Content.ReadAsByteArrayAsync())`

Comment: If the server gives you non-text data flagged as text/plain, surely that must mean there is a bug in the server code? Also, can you try actually downloading it as bytes instead and writing them unencoded to a file? Then check the contents? Try using a hex viewer such as HXD. For instance, could the data be text in UTF-16 encoding, which for normal text would make every other byte a zero-byte, which might trip up a text editor?

Comment: @LasseV.Karlsen: Posted the hex dump

Comment: @LasseV.Karlsen: Indeed If it is read as bytes and written as bytes I can open in a text editor as utf-16. Post as an answer and I will accept it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As was discovered through the comments, the issue was with encoding.

Even though the client code used a string download routine, apparently the server did not specify the encoding [at all/correctly] and thus what was discovered to be UTF16 encoded text was interpreted as something else, most likely UTF8.

The end result was that the file was a bit mangled, and was misinterpreted when opened up later.

Fixing the code to download it as raw bytes, not decoding or encoding them but simply putting them into a file made it possible to open the file as UTF16 and get the text content.

Ideally, the server should specify the encoding used when delivering the content, but sometimes when files are downloaded, it may be that the server code that is delivering the file does not know the encoding of the content of the file, typically because the file was produced by 3rd party code or was already on disk in an unknown encoding.

Comment: Although I send the headers _Accept-Charset_ as _utf-8_ and _User-Agent_ as Firefox or Edge somehow the server/application knows I'm a C# client and insists in _utf-16_. The file is built on demand by the Microstrategy application not from disk.

Answer (score 0):

if it works in browser you can try to add any valid User-Agent header, perhaps there's some trick at the server side

Comment: Did not work: `cliente.DefaultRequestHeaders.UserAgent.ParseAdd("Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; Win64; x64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/42.0.2311.135 Safari/537.36 Edge/12.246");`